# jQuery Jwizard get current step

Tags: jquery, jwizard

I am using jQuery jWizard from [here](http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/)
Thi is my initialization:

```
jQuery("#jWizardResourceCreate").jWizard({
        counter: { enable: true },
        effects: { enable: true },

    });
```

I have 4 steps :

```
<div id="jWizardResourceCreate">
    <div id="step1">

    </div>
    <div id="step2">

    </div>
    <div id="step3">

    </div>
     <div id="step4">

    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to get current step index ,i really need it but can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dataJwizardIdCurrentStep = jQuery(".jw-steps-wrap >div").filter(function () {
                    if (this.style.display == 'block') {
                        return (this.style.display == 'block');
                    }
                });
```